# AWS SES handle doesn't exist mailbox with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-ses, email-spec

I try to use AWS SES for handle some app data on get email.

I've verified mydomain.com with AWS SES. I want handle dynamic email to addresses 1@mydomain.com 2@mydoamin.com, where 1,2 id from database.

I want handle it with AWS lambda, but I can not do it because I get:

> 550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

Is there any way to bypass the creation of mailboxes?

How can I change to email address via SES, for send all emails to one pre existed mailbox?

Comment: Related: [Amazon WorkMail account failing to receive email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47798822/55075)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error.
My problem was RuleSets.

SES>Email receiving>Rules Sets.
There should be rules here that allows your mail ID or any mail to your domain.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error

> 550 5.1.1 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable

is not an AWS Lambda or AWS SES issue. It is an issue on the receiving end of the email. The problem is that there is no one on the receiving end of `1@mydomain.com` to receive the email.

Lambda and SES cannot avoid the issue. To handle the issue, you must resolve it on the receiving end by:

- creating an inbox, or
- setting up aliases, or
- wild-card the emails to a default inbox

The technical steps to accomplish this will depend on your receiving-end mail server.

Comment: Can I change 'To' header in SES rules for change to email address?

Comment: You can change the "To" field, but that just changes where your email will be sent.  The recipient must still exist (same issue as before).

Comment: @MattHouser - I don't think this answers the question. I am running into the same issue - it IS an SES issue, I get the issue when receiving, not sending emails. So it is my Amazon SES account that is receiving the emails; why is SES sending a bounce message *to the sender* (that I am supposed to receive)? The receiving email box doesn't exist but why does that matter? It's an email to doesnotexist@<my domain>.com, I own the domain, so I should be able to parse the incoming email.

Comment: @user3170530 what rules do you have defined in SES for receiving messages? Is your domain configured in SES as a verified domain?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your MX records are [correctly setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ses_region) and [propagated](https://www.whatsmydns.net/).

To check, navigate to your domain's *Hosted zone* in *Route 53*, and you should have the MX records like:

```
10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
20 inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 
30 inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

See also: [Amazon WorkMail account failing to receive email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47798822/55075)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to make sure you have your email domain verified under **Identity Management - Domains** in AWS Console.

After that, you have to verify your RuleSet is active. This means under **Email Receiving - Rule Sets - View Active Rule Set** you have to see your rule using the defined domain.

---

In your particular case:

1. Verify domain mydoamin.com
2. Check if the Active Rule Set really contains the SES rules for 1@mydoamin.com and .2@mydoamin.com

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while setting up email forwarding from one address to another, and ultimately realised that when the SES rule set instructions asked for a 'recipient' email address, it was not the address I was forwarding emails to, but actually the initial email address that was receiving the email.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. While my domain was verified with SES I needed to create an SES identity. After creating the identity everything on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-receive-inbound-emails/ worked as expected.